# Kotlin gzip uncompress fail

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gzip

I try to simplify my java gzip uncompress code to kotlin. But after I changed, it sames broken.

Here is the java code

```java
  public static byte[] uncompress(byte[] compressedBytes) {
    if (null == compressedBytes || compressedBytes.length == 0) {
      return null;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = null;
    ByteArrayInputStream in = null;
    GZIPInputStream gzipInputStream = null;

    try {
      out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      in = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressedBytes);
      gzipInputStream = new GZIPInputStream(in);
      byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
      int n = 0;

      while ((n = gzipInputStream.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, n);
      }

      return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException ignore) {
    } finally {
      CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(gzipInputStream);
      CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(in);
      CloseableUtils.closeQuietly(out);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

This is my kotlin code.

```kotlin
  payload = GZIPInputStream(payload.inputStream())
      .bufferedReader()
      .use { it.readText() }
      .toByteArray()
```

And I got this error.

```
com.google.protobuf.nano.InvalidProtocolBufferNanoException: While parsing a protocol message, the input ended unexpectedly in the middle of a field.  This could mean either than the input has been truncated or that an embedded message misreported its own length.
```

It seems that the decompression process was interrupted by reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [readText(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8)](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-text.html) decodes the bytes into UTF-8 character set, which is why it says "This could mean either than the input has been truncated" it probably have tried to convert 8-bits into a `Char` and build a String out of it.

Use the [readBytes()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-bytes.html) to get `ByteArray` which is represented same as `byte[]` in JVM platform.

Example:

```kotlin
GZIPInputStream(payload.inputStream())
      .bufferedReader()
      .use { it.readBytes() }
```

#### Edit:

For reading bytes, you shouldn't be using the `Reader`, it is meant for reading the Text in UTF-8 format as defined in the Kotlin's `InputStream.bufferedReader`:

```kotlin
public inline fun InputStream.bufferedReader(charset: Charset = Charsets.UTF_8): BufferedReader = reader(charset).buffered()
```

The [InputStream.readBytes()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/read-bytes.html) will read the bytes at a buffer of 8KB itself.

```kotlin
public fun InputStream.readBytes(): ByteArray {
    val buffer = ByteArrayOutputStream(maxOf(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE, this.available()))
    copyTo(buffer)
    return buffer.toByteArray()
}
// This copies with 8KB buffer automatically
// DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 8 * 1024
public fun InputStream.copyTo(out: OutputStream, bufferSize: Int = DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE): Long {
    var bytesCopied: Long = 0
    val buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
    var bytes = read(buffer)
    while (bytes >= 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, bytes)
        bytesCopied += bytes
        bytes = read(buffer)
    }
    return bytesCopied
}
```

So you just have to do:

```kotlin
GZIPInputStream(payload.inputStream()).use { it.readBytes() }
```

Comment: Yes you are right, but the 'BufferReader' sames do not have 'readBytes' method.

Comment: @Aquarids ah, [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) is documented as `Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as to provide for the efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines.` It is actually defined for the purpose of reading characters, you should just load it without a Reader. Check the update.

Answer (score -1):

use the following function:

```
    fun File.unzip(unzipLocationRoot: File? = null) {

    val rootFolder = unzipLocationRoot
        ?: File(parentFile.absolutePath + File.separator + nameWithoutExtension)
    if (!rootFolder.exists()) {
        rootFolder.mkdirs()
    }

    ZipFile(this).use { zip ->
        zip
            .entries()
            .asSequence()
            .map {
                val outputFile = File(rootFolder.absolutePath + File.separator + it.name)
                ZipIO(it, outputFile)
            }
            .map {
                it.output.parentFile?.run {
                    if (!exists()) mkdirs()
                }
                it
            }
            .filter { !it.entry.isDirectory }
            .forEach { (entry, output) ->
                zip.getInputStream(entry).use { input ->
                    output.outputStream().use { output ->
                        input.copyTo(output)
                    }
                }
            }
    }

}
```

Pass the file as a parameter as follow:

```
val zipFile = File(your file directory, your file name)
            zipFile.unzip()
```

Hope this would help